# .NET MAUI Reference Image from app bundle for sharing

Tags: maui

I'd like to share an image which is shipped as part of the app bundle. Following code works:

```
        await using Stream inputStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("fstest.png");
        string targetFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "fstest.png");

        using FileStream outputStream = File.Create(targetFile);
        await inputStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
        outputStream.Close();
        await Share.Default.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
        {
            Title = "Share Image",
            File = new ShareFile(targetFile)
        });
```

Is there a way to reference bundled image from ShareFileRequest directly ? It does not accept a stream. But copying it first to data directory sounds like a complicated way of doing this.

Comment: I don't think there's any other simpler way to directly refer the bundled image, since you have made it worked, you can just copy it first to data directory, a little trivial but it's working.